# wxPython RichTextCtrl much slower than tkInter Text?

Tags: python, performance, wxpython, tkinter, richtextediting

I've made a small tool that parses a chunk of text, does some simple processing (retrieves values from a dictionary, a few regex, etc.) and then spits the results.

In order to make easier to read the results, I made two graphic ports, one with tkInter and other with wxPython, so the output is nicely displayed in a Text Area with some words having different colours.

The tkInter implementation uses `Tkinter.Text` object and to apply the colours to the words uses tags (configured with the method `Tkinter.Text.tag_config` and passing them to `Tkinter.Text.insert`), and the measured while outputting about 400 different coloured words is < 0.02s.

The wxPython implementation uses `wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl` and to apply the colours to the words uses `wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.BeginTextColour` and then `wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.AppendText`; the performance is ridiculous, it takes abut 1.4s to do the same job that only took 0.02s to the tkInter port.

Is this an intrinsic problem of the RichTextCtrl widget, the wxPython bindings, or there is some way to speed it up?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you working on? I have noticed that wxPython is a whole lot slower on Linux than on Windows.

Comment: Linux... I could try it on windows to see if it gets better.

Comment: I've tested it on Windows and indeed faster (now it takes about half time, around 0.6s), but still is almost thirty times slower than the tkInter version :-s

Comment: Try posting to the wxPython-users group to see if Robin has any insight.  I bet the gurus on there can get your code faster.  http://groups.google.com/group/wxPython-users

Comment: Have you tried using Freeze() and Thaw() to only update the display after you are done appending the coloured text?

Comment: will you post some sample code, so that we can tweak it and see

Comment: @mghie Thanks, I didn't know about these methods, that solved the problem! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm copying here the comment that solved the problem:

> Have you tried using Freeze() and
>   Thaw() to only update the display
>   after you are done appending the
>   coloured text? – mghie Jun 30 at 7:20

Answer (score 0):

It kind of avoids the question slightly, but could you use wxStyledTextCtrl instead?